# Process specific ulimit still low after changes to soft and hard ulimits

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, ulimit

I'm having trouble with increasing the open-files ulimit (`ulimit -n`) for a particular process on a Debian 6 server.

AFAIK I've done everything to change the servers hard and soft limits in this case, (`ulimit -n` shows 200000), but when I check the `/proc/<process_id>/limits` file it's still showing the old limits:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

---

*The steps that I have already taken to permanently increase the ulimits are:*

**Added to /etc/profile:**

```
# set ulimit n permanetly
ulimit -n 200000
```

**Added to /etc/security/limits.conf:**

```
*       soft    nofile  200000
*       hard    nofile  200000
```

**Uncommented this lime in /etc/pam.d/su**

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

**What am I missing?** Thank you!

---

Other (relevant?) info:

- The process is started in a `init.d` script with `start-stop-daemon`
- The `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think /etc/pam.d/su/etc/pam.d/su is for su command, maybe put pam_limits.so in /etc/pam.d/login or /etc/pam.d/system-account solve this issue.
And after change a system-account limits, you need to restart.